# Display Specific Text if Adjacent Cell to Referenced Cell is "X"

Tags: if-statement, reference

I'm building a spreadsheet that will show the following:

**Sheet 2** has a prepoluated list of a Personal and Corporate Accounts.

**Sheet 1** has a dropdown selection with those accounts and a percentage showing if that expenditure has a business proponent. If a personal account was used but there was a business proporent to that purchase we need a column to indicate that there is a reimbursement required.

If the cell on Sheet2 adjacent right of the selected 'account' in Sheet1,C2 shows "Personal" **AND** cell Sheet1,A2 has a % greater than 0%, display "YES", OTHERWISE "NO".

Example Spreadsheet attached:

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAI35.png)
[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYreF.png)

This one is a bit out of my field, I am comfortable with the IF forumala, but I've had difficulty with how to check the adjacent cell of the referenced cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ChatGPT and got the answer:

```
=IF(AND(VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$100,2,FALSE)="Personal",A2>0),"YES","NO")
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you've already validated that this answer works correctly in your workbook?

Comment: Yes I can confirm it did